# How to update an embedded entity reference inside an entity with JPQL?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have a question how to update an embedded entity, which is part of another entity in JPQL. I mean how can I write the update statement for the following case:

EntityA:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTITY_A")
public class EntityA {

@Embedded
private EmbeddedEntity embeddedEntity;
@Column(name="NORMAL_STRING")
private String normalString;
}
```

EmbeddedEntity:

```java
@Embeddable
public class EmbeddedEntity {

private String normalString2;
}
```

The database table "Entity_A" looks like this

```
Table ENTITY_A
-  normal_string varchar2 not null
-  normal_string2 varchar2 not null
```

Is there the possibility to write 1 JPQL update Statement to update both properties: "normalString" and "normalString2"?
How would this JPQL statement looks like?

I really appreciate your advice.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA):

```java
int updateEntity(String string1, String string2) {

    FluentQuery query = FluentJPA.SQL((EntityA a) -> {
        UPDATE(a).SET(() -> {
            a.setNormalString(string1);
            a.getEmbeddedEntity().setNormalString2(string2);
        });
    });

    return query.createQuery(em).executeUpdate();
}
```

Resulting SQL:

```
UPDATE ENTITY_A SET NORMAL_STRING = ?1
normal_string2 = ?2
```

- Disclaimer, I'm a FluentJPA developer.